# Why are four of my HTTPCalloutMock Classes counting toward code coverage?

Tags: salesforce

I have 7 HTTPCalloutMock classes, with associated test classes that use them.

However, when checking my code coverage I notice that only 4 of them are listed and have 0% covered. I am trying to get 90% and these 4 classes are cramping my style.

I can detect no difference between the classes that get covered and those that do not. Attached is the pertinent code for a class that is not getting covered, despite the class being called (see the TestPardot() testMedthod and note the system asserts that should fail if the mock was not called)

[image: Code Coverage and Mock code]

[image: TestMethod code]

Answer (score 0):

This is because your test class contains methods not marked as test methods. What is your goal? Do you want 100% coverage on this class or for this class to omitted from the code coverage totals?

If you want 100% coverage, remove the @isTest annotation and add logic to only run the code when Test.isRunningTest() == TRUE.

If you want to omit it from the code coverage totals, you will need to re-work it so that it only includes test methods.

The link below show some scenarios, work-arounds, and self-evaluation tools.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Why-is-a-Test-class-evaluated-as-part-of-the-Organization-s-Code-Coverage&language=en_US&type=1

You can also try the @testSetup annotation on the mockPardotWSCall method. I don't know how that will affect the code coverage.